# firebase code organization for util methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have my index.js like below

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as rp from "request-promise-native";
import * as btoa from "btoa";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as SendGrid from '@sendgrid/mail';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

export const dialog_handler = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    console.log("in dialog_handler request payload is:" + request.body.payload)
    const reqParams = JSON.parse(request.body.payload)

    const callbackId = reqParams.callback_id
    console.log(":::::::::::::::Callback Id:" + callbackId)
    const submission = reqParams.submission
    console.log(submission )
    let payload = {}

    if(callbackId === 'send_feedback'){
        await admin.database().ref("feedback").push(submission);
        payload = { "attachments": [
            {
                "fallback": "Feedback submitted",
                "title": "Feedback submitted. We will get back to you as soon as possible."
            }]
       }

    }
}
```

The above actual code does not matter. the main thing is below payload that is sort of reusable code for me. how can i move it out of index.ts and just refer it and keep my index.tx small.

```
 payload = { "attachments": [
                {
                    "fallback": "Feedback submitted",
                    "title": "Feedback submitted. We will get back to you as soon as possible."
                }]
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Cloud Functions so much as it has to do with TypeScript module syntax and resolution.

You can have an adjacent file `payload.ts` which looks like this:

```
export const payload = { "attachments": [{
                "fallback": "Feedback submitted",
                "title": "Feedback submitted. We will get back to you as soon as possible."
            }]
       }
```

Then you can get a hold of its value from another file:

```
import { payload } from "./payload"
```

You might want to read up on [module resolution in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).